# Versionamento de projeto laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, versionamento

Eu faço um projeto em Laravel 5.1 e utilizo o XAMPP e todas as configurações como banco de dados esta local,(computador de casa) etc. Só que eu eu subi (*push*) para o Github esse projeto só que quando eu vou no PC do trabalho eu clono o projeto e não funciona lógico.

Por que não tem a base de dados nesse caso tenho que configurar o arquivo `.env`? E recriar a base de dados? E tem mais algum arquivo que tenho que configurar?

Comment: mano, se tiver de fato puxando as configs do .env é só isso mesmo, altera ele conforme a necessidade, cria o bd e roda o migrate.

Comment: php artisan make:migrate tipo assim?

Comment: php artisan migrate

Comment: eu observei com que o arquivo .env quando dei um push não veio, eu tive que recriar

Comment: geralmente ele nem vai pro git no push, ai vc usa o .env.example para criar o seu .env no local que vai trabalhar

Comment: É por isso que a galera tem que começar usar o migrate, ao invés de simplesmente fazer  um "dumpão" do PHPmyAdmin

Comment: @Raylan Soares obrigado nesse caso quando for fazer a configuração do banco inves de utilizar o .env, eu utilizo o .env.example, e quanto ao arquivo app_key? eu colo a do arquivo .env?

Comment: não, vc vai copiar o ".env.example" e renomear a cópia para ".env" e preencher com os dados

Comment: quanto a key acho q basta dar um "php artisan key:generate"

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O arquivo **.env** fica apenas na máquina em que estamos trabalhando, quando enviamos o projeto para o git esse arquivo geralmente não é enviado.

Para configurar sua aplicação em outro local de trabalho faça o seguinte:

1. Clone seu projeto do git.
2. Crie uma cópia do **.env.example**, renomeie para **.env** e preencha com os
   dados locais.
3. Crie seu banco de dados.
4. rode um migrate: `php artisan migrate`.

**Obs:** Para gerar uma nova key basta rodar o comando `php artisan key:generate`.